# Choose value from column with column name to choose in a separate column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with different data columns (say x, y, z) and another column which specifies which one to choose. I want to use dplyr::mutate (or similar) to make a new column that has the value corresponding to value in the column specified by "choose". I want to keep all the columns in the first place. In my real data I also have a few other columns with metadata.

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)
testdf <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 11:15, z = 101:105, choose = c("z","y","x","y","z"))
```

I can make this work in my example using `case_when` but in my actual script the column names and choose column are generated and may have different values, so I don't want to hardcode what names there could be.

Desired output/test

```
mutate(testdf, selectedValue = case_when(choose == "x" ~x,
                                     choose == "y"~ y,
                                     choose == "z"~ z, T~NA_integer_))

#>   x  y   z choose selectedValue
#> 1 1 11 101      z           101
#> 2 2 12 102      y            12
#> 3 3 13 103      x             3
#> 4 4 14 104      y            14
#> 5 5 15 105      z           105
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution. This is a case where I don't think the dplyr solutions are more human readable than other solutions (base r and data.table specifically).

```r
library(data.table)
testdt <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 11:15, z = 101:105, choose = c("z","y","x","y","z"))
testdt[,selectedValue := get(choose), by = choose]
testdt
#>    x  y   z choose selectedValue
#> 1: 1 11 101      z           101
#> 2: 2 12 102      y            12
#> 3: 3 13 103      x             3
#> 4: 4 14 104      y            14
#> 5: 5 15 105      z           105
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Normally I really struggle to understand what's going on with data.table but I agree here it is actually quite readable

Answer (score 4):

If you use `purrr` with `dplyr`:

```r
testdf %>%
    mutate(selectedValue = purrr::map2_dbl(row_number(),choose,~testdf[.x,.y]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution and does use mutate as I asked. In this case I went for the data.table as I think (unusually) it's more readable than the tidyverse solution and this script will be being used by noobs. But I can imagine using this technique in the future so thanks

Comment: map2_dbl can be replaced by `imap_dbl` in this case

Answer (score 1):

A base R way would be to create a row/column index matrix to subset from `testdf`. We use `match` to get column index and create a sequential counter for row.

```
testdf$selectedvalue <- testdf[cbind(seq_len(nrow(testdf)), 
                               match(testdf$choose, names(testdf)))]
testdf
#  x  y   z choose selectedvalue
#1 1 11 101      z           101
#2 2 12 102      y            12
#3 3 13 103      x             3
#4 4 14 104      y            14
#5 5 15 105      z           105
```