# How to create new column with an existing value conditional on another column in long format?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset in long format (each person has 3 rows).

I'm trying to create a new variable (`newvar`) based on the combination of two other columns. In the example data below, I want `newvar` to equal the value of either `a`, `b`, or `c` depending on the value of the column `order`

If `order=1`, then `newvar` should take the value from `a`.
If `order=2`, `newvar` should take the value from `b`.
If `order=3`, `newvar` should take the value from `c`.

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
b <- c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
c <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA)
order <- c(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(id, a, b, c, order)

df$newvar[df$order == 1] <- df$a
df$newvar[df$order == 2] <- df$b
df$newvar[df$order == 3] <- df$c
```

Simply assigning the values results in several errors. 
I also receive an error message "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

The solutions offered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983923/r-dplyr-choose-value-from-column-with-column-name-to-choose-in-a-separate-column) don't work.

I'd like the values of `newvar` to be as follows:
[image: correct values of newvar]

Comment: `df[cbind(1:NROW(df), df$order + 1)]`

Comment: @yifyan So this solution doesn't work for my specific application. I need something that I can apply to different datasets. I've also tried each of the solutions in the linked "duplicate" questions but they don't work either.